# How to capitalize the first letter of the day + outline to the left

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

At the moment I'm using the Opening Hours plugin on Wordpress (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-opening-hours/ ) and I have a question about the shortcode. FYI: I'm using Wordpress and Elementor.

At the moment the following can be seen on my website (text is in Dutch): https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBsJz.jpg

The following code has been used:

```
[op-overview set_id=".."  show_closed_days="true" show_description="false" highlight="day" compress="true" include_io="true" include_holidays="true" template="list" caption_closed="Gesloten" style="color:#ffffff;"]
```

I would like to capitalize the first letter of the day and outline the opening hours (the numbers) to the left, so this is in line with the days. However, I have no idea how to code this eventhough it seems to be a quite easy task. Is anyone able to help me out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to show us the relevant HTML and CSS that the plugin has created.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: Here is the HTML from his site that was output by the plugin:

```
<dl class="op-list op-list-overview">
    <dt class="op-cell op-cell-heading highlighted">maandag – vrijdag</dt>
    <dd class="op-cell op-cell-periods highlighted"><span class="op-period-time ">08:00 – 17:30</span></dd>
    <dt class="op-cell op-cell-heading ">zaterdag</dt>
    <dd class="op-cell op-cell-periods "><span class="op-period-time ">08:30 – 12:00</span></dd>
    <dt class="op-cell op-cell-heading ">zondag</dt>
    <dd class="op-cell op-cell-periods "><span class="op-closed">Gesloten</span></dd>
</dl>
```

And here is the custom css to accomplish the changes:

```
.op-list-overview .op-cell.op-cell-heading {
    text-transform: capitalize; /*Capitalizes the first letter of every word in the heading cell with the days in it.*/
}
.op-list-overview .op-cell.op-cell-periods {
    margin-left:  0; /*Clears the left margin on the hours*/
    margin-bottom: 5px; /*for space beneath the hours*/
}
```

Not seeing your site I wouldn't be able to tell if those work.

To add custom CSS to WordPress, log into the dashboard and, in the left menu, click "Appearance" then "Customize." In the customizer, the bottom option on the left should be "Additional CSS." That will give you a text box where you can add code like the CSS I provided above. Just be careful adding code you don't understand from someone you don't know (like me). If you need to, google some of the things in my code to make sure you know what it is and what it's doing.

Comment: I downloaded the plugin and looked at the code that they use to generate that shortcode. This might work to solve your problem now

Comment: I fixed the css. I'll edit my answer to add instructions for custom css.

Comment: Ok, I've added instructions for adding the custom css to your WordPress site.

Comment: Thank you for your help, much appreciated. It does work properly now, just the way I wanted. However, I would like to point out that after .op-cell.op-cell-periods there is a "{". Just in case anyone else want to use this solution as well. 

Do you might know as well how I can add an enter after the hours through css lines? So there is some space between the above hours and then the following day?

Comment: You could add `margin-bottom: 5px;` to the `.op-list-overview .op-cell.op-cell-periods` block. You can change the 5px to any amount that looks good to you. I'll add it to the answer. And I fixed the missing `{` also, thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to add a css line to change the language as well? Since the plugin now automatically uses the language that is used in Wordpress itself, would be better to have it work independently

Comment: Sorry, no. CSS wouldn't be able to do that as far as I know. CSS is meant to handle styling and layout, not actual content. You could probably use Javascript to swap it out, but that would get pretty hackish.